# PHP files not executing inside include statements

Tags: php, nginx

I have an extraordinarily simple website:

index.html contains:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

It is in /usr/share/nginx/html

footer.php is in the same directory and is:

```
<?php
echo "<p>printed!!</p>";
?>
```

When I go to http://MY_IP_address/footer.php I get the proper output of just a blank page with "printed!!" at the top left.

When I go to http://MY_IP_address/ I get:
"
Welcome to my home page!

Some text.

Some more text.
"

But I do not get "printed!!" written anywhere.

I am assuming that somewhere I missed something in my config files, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Can you rename index.html to index.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file which contained `include()` is a file with `.html` extension, thus it's not interpreted by Apache. Thus, the code in `index.html` was not included. (Credits to @RiggsFolly for the improved explanation)

Unless your server is set to parse `.html` files as PHP, it will not be included.

Thus you'll need to rename it to `index.php`.

> The `include()` function in PHP includes code from other PHP files and copies them into the file that uses the include statement.

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php-include/info
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: You can include any type of file. But it wont get passed to the PHP Parser unless it has a .php extension

Comment: This did it, I will accept the answer once S.O. allows. thanks

Comment: Actually the issue was that the file containing the PHP statement `include` was a file with an `.html` extension and therefore was not being passed to the PHP Interpreter by Apache. So of course any PHP code in a file that is not being interpreted by the PHP interpreter can not be executed.

Comment: Minor Nitpick: `unless it has a .php extension` not necessarily. *unless your web server is set to parse the included file as PHP* :)

Comment: @HankyPanky Very true, but I am guessing thats a bit beyond the OP when they did not yet know a PHP script had to be in a file with a `.php` extension in a default PHP setup.

Comment: Yep absolutely. Just having some fun :)

Comment: @Rorschach You're welcome! Glad that it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Php tags(`<?php ?>`) can only be parsed when file extension is php. 
So,
Change file name from `index.html` to `index.php`

Comment: It might be useful to add a little explanation as to why this is necessary. Otherwise the COMMENT given by @Nikhil says everything that this answer (really just a comment) says.